# OpenSSH Users and SFTP

Tags: openssh, sftp

I added users to my server, but when I try to login, it prompts me for a password, which I never put in. Do any of you know what the default password is? Also, I would like to setup SFTP, so can anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

### You cannot use SSH to login to a User Account that does not exist on the host machine or that does not yet have a password

To use OpenSSH, your host machine running the `ssh` service must have at least one `<username>` with a corresponding password.  If the `<username>` on the host machine that you would like to use does not yet have a password, on the host machine do:

```
sudo passwd username
```

Now you should be able to login to your host machine using `ssh` from a client machine.

- Note that SFTP is included in the ssh daemon, so in a terminal on the client machine:

  ```
  sftp user@ip.address
  ```

### Alternatively, if you simply want to use `sftp` to visually access the host machine's filesystem (e.g., using Nautilus)

1. Open Nautilus on the client machine
2. Select File > Connect to Server
3. Type: `SSH`
4. Server: Enter your host machine's IP address
5. Port: port number specified in host machine's `sshd_config` file
6. User name: username
7. Password: password

[image]

Comment: Do I need to be in an certain directory for this command? I'm a Linux newbie.

Comment: No, you can execute it from any directory. :)

Comment: When I do the command it gives me a no user name error. Do I need to create an account for SSH?

Comment: You need to replace username by the username of the user you add on the server and you need to execute this command on the server.